# Uniform distribution and expectation

Tags: probability, expectation, uniform-distribution

Let $U \sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$, $X=U^2$ and $Y=e^X$. Compute $E[Y]$ (leave answer as an integral).
So essentially we need to compute $E[e^{U^2}]$? I am a little confused how to approach this problem?

Comment: That is correct.  It will come to $\displaystyle\int_0^1 e^{u^2} f(u)\,du$ where $f$ is the density function for this distribution.  And for this distribution, the density function is quite simple. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ is the density of random variable $X$, then $E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x)dx$. In your case, $Y=g(U)=\exp(U^2)$. So

$$E[Y]=\int_{0}^1 \exp(U^2)\cdot 1\cdot du$$

Comment: so this is the final answer, as we can't take antiderivative?

Comment: @Dee Chantelle: you can't find an easy anti derivative so it's probably what the problem is asking for. You can express the integral in terms of the Erf error function integral but not much more.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to find the distribution of $X$. If $0<x<1$ then
$$F_X(x) = \mathbb P(X\leqslant x) = \mathbb P(U^2 \leqslant x) = \mathbb P(U \leqslant \sqrt x)=\sqrt x. $$
So the density is obtained by differentiating:
$$f(x) = \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx} F(x) = \frac12 x^{-\frac12},\quad 0<x<1. $$
Now we compute
\begin{align} \mathbb E[Y] &= \mathbb E\left[e^X\right]\\
&= \int_0^1 e^x\frac12 x^{-\frac12}\mathsf dx
\end{align}
Unfortunately, the function $x\mapsto e^x\frac12 x^{-\frac12}$ does not have an antiderivative which can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. The approach used by @Alex R. yields
$$\mathbb E[Y] = \int_0^1 e^{u^2}\mathsf du, $$
(which is the same value.)